# Problem aligning with alignat

Tags: amsmath, alignat

I have another problem with this alignation. I dont know how to align the p function between G and Aut(V_K).

Thanks again for all your support.

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\theta:\mathcal{E}(K|k)&\longrightarrow& H^{1}(G,\Aut(V_{K})) \\
(V',x')&\longmapsto&p:G &\longrightarrow\Aut(V_{K}) \\
&&s&\longmapsto p_s=f^{-1}\circ s(f)=f^{-1}\circ s\circ f\circ s^{-1}.
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

Comment: please always post _complete_ documents (as in the answer to the previous question) otherwise it just makes it harder for anyone to test your code. But this seems to be the same issue as the question just asked, you have an unwanted `&` after the arrow.

Comment: Never post the same question twice, even from different accounts.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use nested `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\theta:\mathcal{E}(K|k)&\longrightarrow H^{1}(G,\Aut(V_{K})) \\
(V',x')&\longmapsto
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  p:G &\longrightarrow\Aut(V_{K}) \\
  s&\longmapsto p_s=f^{-1}\circ s(f)=f^{-1}\circ s\circ f\circ s^{-1}.
  \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Better with `\colon` instead of `:`; also, in my opinion, normal length arrows are nicer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\theta\colon\mathcal{E}(K|k)&\rightarrow H^{1}(G,\Aut(V_{K})) \\
(V',x')&\mapsto
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  p\colon G &\rightarrow\Aut(V_{K}) \\
  s&\mapsto p_s=f^{-1}\circ s(f)=f^{-1}\circ s\circ f\circ s^{-1}.
  \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]